# How to thin an image borders with specific pixel size? OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to thin an image by making the border pixels of size 16x24 becoming 0. I'm not trying to get the skeletal image, I'm just trying to reduce the size of the white area. Any methods that I could use? Enlighten me please.

This is the sample image that i'm trying to thin. It is made of 16x24 white blocks

[image]

## **EDIT**

I tried to use this

```
cv::Mat img=cv::imread("image.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);//image is in binary
cv::Mat mask = img > 0; 

Mat kernel = Mat::ones( 16, 24, CV_8U );
erode(mask,mask,kernel);
```

But the result i got was this

[image]

which is not exactly what i wanted. I want to maintain the exact same shape with just 16x24 pixels of white shaved off from the border. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: I'm trying to reduce the size of the white surrounding area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [Erode](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html#erosion) your image.
[Another Description](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#erosion)

Comment: hi there. I can't get the exact shape from eroding. Is my kernel wrongly defined? I updated the question. Please check. Thanks

Comment: What do u exactly mean by 16x24 pixel? Erosion will actually fill white holes in image if u want that accurate effect then i am afraid that erosion is not thr solution.

Comment: The white pixels are constructed from 16x24 pixel blocks. Means that the values inside each 16x24 pixels blocks are of the same value. Is there a better method to do the shrinking?

Comment: I am not sure of any other method. May be you can try playing with your erosion kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but you should erode your image using a kernel which is twice the size you want to get rid of plus one, like:

```
Mat kernel = Mat::ones( 24*2+1, 16*2+1, CV_8U );
```

Notice I changed the places of the height and width of the block, I only know opencv from Python, but I am pretty sure the order is the same as in Python.